Repeated measurements of proportions with no information on individual subjects
I am working on a dataset (not mine) that includes repeated measurements of proportions, measured at 50 equally spaced time points. There are two groups. Group A has 65 individuals, and group B has 23 individuals. For each time point, the data includes the number of individuals per group that are preening. For example at the first time point, 10 out of 65 individuals from group A are preening, and 55 are not. At the next time point, for example 11 out of 65 are preening, but I don't know if these include the same 10 individuals from before, or different ones.
How can I compare the average proportions preening in the two groups?
My concerns are that because they are repeated measurements, the data points are not independent, but since there's no information about individuals, I can't use a random effect for subject ID.
Also, under the assumption that all individuals of the same group spend the same amount of time preening, can the mean proportion of a group serve as an estimation of the ratio of time that an individual of said group spends preening?
Here are the first 3 and last 3 rows of the data set.


Could you tell ussome more? Animals (which?) or people are preening? How are the groups defined? Treatments? ...
